# Why is my click event handler not firing for a dynamically added link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

I am working on dynamically adding a link with a click event handler after a series of span tags on a page. The link is being added to the page, but when clicked the event handler is not firing. There are no errors recorded in the web console. I am sure that I am missing something *obvious* in the below code:

```js
function changeClicked (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('should work');
}

function initChangeOwner() {
    var changeLink = $('<a />', {
        href: '#',
        text: 'change',
        'class': 'changeLink',
        click: changeClicked
    });

    var licenseFor = $('[id*="LicenseFor"]').after(changeLink);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    initChangeOwner();
    // other inits
});
```

Why is my click event handler not firing? For those who like to fiddle I have setup [an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahsteele/xUjTd/1/).

<sub>* This is an older application which utilizes jQuery 1.4.1. Unfortunately, now is not the time to update the reference to a new version.</sub>

Comment: The aactual problem is preplexing, its more preplexing after I see different versions of working answers :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to get fancy on dynamic bindings in your particular case.
Seeing you are in control when adding the elements and you want to bind the event at that time you can just bind you click event separately after you attached the elements.

```
function initChangeOwner() {
    var changeLink = $('<a />', {
        href: '#',
        text: 'change',
        'class': 'changeLink'
    });

    var licenseFor = $('[id*="LicenseFor"]').after(changeLink);

    // Now the elements exist and you can bind the click event using the 'changeLink' class as a selector.
    $(".changeLink").click(function(event){changeClicked(event);});

}
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/40/) - Bind after elements are created

Comment: So that worked as [did mcpDESIGNS answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12219810/61654). I know why this works, but what's the "issue" with my initial version?

Comment: It looks like in 1.4.4 there is some sort of Bug, in that you can't add these click / onclick attributes like that to an element. (On a side note you don't want to use those regardless, each one individually creates a scripts file in IE (slows down performance). It also looks like your original code works in later versions of jQuery, just tried it in 1.8 worked fine.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS If the problem is with the way he attached lcik event, then this should work right? But it isnt http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/56/

Comment: Yeah but as @Francois pointed out, it needs to be placed -after- var licenseFor (this is when it is put into the DOM). In my version I used .live(), which just waits for the event to bubble up, basically the same thing.

Comment: @sabithpocker: I think the main issue with using the `changeLink` object directly as that it has no selector value. `console.log(changeLink.selector);` outputs an empty string. While `console.log($(".changeLink").selector);` outputs the expected selector `.changeLink`. While `changeLink` is a HTML element you can attach using `after` it doesn't seem to be a valid selector itself.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/57/ the selector is null, but the binding is fine.

Comment: @sabithpocker: In fiddle 56 the changeLink object was used to bind  i.e: `changeLink.click(...)` which doesn't work due to the missing selector. However, when you are using the `.each` in fiddle 57 you are specifying the click within the `changeLink` element declaration directly, hence you are not using the selector of `changeLink`.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Here is fiddle 56 with some logs, the binding actually worked when element is created, but after inserting the same element multiple times into DOM the event got lost. http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/59/

Comment: I think the problem is with first attaching an event to changeLink and then inserting that multiple times into the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/60/

Comment: @sabithpocker: `console.log(changeLink.data('events').click);` will always show you the events even after they are inserted into the DOM, so they don't get lost. They are still attached to `changeLink`. I would assume the the reason why `console.log($('#LicenseFor1 a .changeLink').data('events').click)` is `undefined` is because the event was not bound to that selector but was bound to `changeLink` an object in memory instead. I'm only guess off course.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Check this case where I inserted the elementonly once into DOM, its working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/61/

Comment: @sabithpocker: This is very interesting. When I get home I check this out and we can keep chatting about this in chat if you want as this is very interestign alright.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16108/discussion-between-francois-wahl-and-sabithpocker)

Answer (score 2):

Normally i'd say use `.on()` but looks like you're using jQuery 1.4.4.

Add a `.live()` event for the click like so: and it all works:

```
$('.changeLink').live('click', function (e) {
   changeClicked(e); 
});
```

It looks like in 1.4.4 there is some sort of Bug, in that you can't add these click / onclick attributes like that to an element. (*On a side note::* you **don't want to use click/onclick/onmouseover/etc on elements** regardless, each one individually (per element) creates a scripts file in IE (slows down performance). It also looks like your original code works in later versions of jQuery, just tried it in 1.8 worked fine.

Also, use `return false;` within your changeClicked() function (it does both `stopPropagation & preventDefault` for you, and anything afterwards won't run, along with the `href="#"` attribute of the anchor.

```
function changeClicked(e) {
    console.log('here we are');

    return false; // stops link - preventDefault & stopPropagation
    console.log('it WONT get here');
}
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KfFv3/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on `return false`. Had forgotten it was preferred to `preventDefault`.

Comment: @mcpDesigns: As a side-note: In jQuery 1.4.2 delegate replaced live and is the preferred method of binding (until 1.7 where they are all repelaced by `on()`). While live works perfectly well, it does bubble up all the way to the document and has quite a few drawbacks which are listed in the docs. Using delegate instead would let you bind the event to the closest static element and lets you specify the selector for the dynamic element within. `$("#MyStaticElement").delegate(".changeLink", "click", function(){...})` this wil only bubble up to the specified closest static element.

Comment: Very true! I'll switch it over to delegate, forgot about that damn thing haha

Answer (score 2):

Restructure your code like:

```
function initChangeOwner() {
    $('[id*="LicenseFor"]').each(function(){
        var changeLink = $('<a />', {
            href: '#',
            text: 'change',
            'class': 'changeLink',
            click: changeClicked
        });
       $(this) .after(changeLink);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/48/ This is working fine

I think the problem is with first attaching an event to changeLink and then inserting that multiple times into the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/60/

Comment: What is it about the `.each` vs. utilizing `.after` that is making the difference?

Comment: One thig is that earlier you created one changeLink that you inserted multiple times, now you create a changeLink for each LicenceFor. Bit I am astill looking into why it didnt work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The function should like this:

```
function initChangeOwner() {
  $('[id*="LicenseFor"]').each(function(index){
    var changeLink = $('<a />', {
    href: '#',
    text: 'change',
    'class': 'changeLink',
     click: changeClicked
   });

    $(this).after(changeLink);
  });
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xUjTd/47/)